# Python, String to JSON?

Tags: python, linux, json

In Fedora 17 64bit while using netifaces and json imports.

I'm trying to get this format in JSON

> ```
> "net_info" : [
>             {"nic" : ..., "mac" : ..., "ip" : ...},
>             {"nic" : ..., "mac" : ..., "ip" : ...},
>             {"nic" : ..., "mac" : ..., "ip" : ...},
>             ]
> ```

I'm currently using a `string` and just appending to it, and I get this:

```
"'net_info': [{'nic':eth0,'mac':6c:f0:49:0f:e1:c2,'ip':192.168.1.116},]"
```

This may not work due to the quotes at the beginning and the end of each string; is there a better way of accomplishing this? I was thinking of using a List of Dictionaries but ended up trying strings first, not sure what would best in this case.

**Here's my code that takes in 3 lists:**

```
def json_serialize(ip=[],mac=[],nic=[]):
    jsonDump = "'net_info': ["
    for i,item in enumerate(ip):
        jsonDump += "{'interface_name':" + nic[i] +",'mac':" 
                      + mac[i] + ",'ip':" + ip[i] +"},"
        jsonDump += "]"
        print jsonDump.strip()

    #Testing output after its passed in to json.dumps(), it now has quotes at beginning
    #and end of string...?
    print "\n"
    print     json.dumps(jsonDump)
```

Comment: What you are producing is not valid JSON. You'd need a `{`..`}` around it for starters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a python `dict` with a contained `list` instead, then dump *that* to JSON in one go:

```
def json_serialize(ip, mac, nic):
    net_info = []
    for ipaddr, macaddr, nicname in zip(ip, mac, nic):
        net_info.append({
            'interface_name': nicaddr,
            'mac': macaddr,
            'ip': ipaddr
        })
    return json.dumps({'net_info': net_info})
```

Your desired output format seems to be missing the outer `{` and `}` brackets to mark it a proper JSON object. If you really *have* to produce that output (so missing those brackets), just remove them again:

```
print json_serialize(ip, mac, nic)[1:-1]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was an extremely fast response and a valid one too!! :) Take care, i will accept this answer ASAP.